# What are good point and features for each protocol in jboss remote naming?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly, jndi

JBoss uses three different protocols that can be used for calling remote EJB: **remote**, **ejb** i **http-remote**. AFAIK there was one more - **jnp**, but it is already abandoned. Each are very shallow described in **Wildfly 10** documentation here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Remote+JNDI+Reference 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Remote+JNDI+Reference+Update+Draft

For me, interesting is **http-remoting** comparing to **ejb**. But I cannot find any information about **http-remoting**. I am especially interested in load balancing between servers, that have the same stateless bean deployed. Protocol **http-remoting** uses http calls, right? That mean I can use some external tool to better distribute calls between servers.

Answer (score 0):

- **http-remoting** basically the same as **remoting** but it runs over the http port of the WildFly and uses http upgrade to switch to **remoting**
- **remoting** is a binary protocol introduces in JBoss AS 7 and thus can be used for compatibility or if you want to have remoting on a port seperate from http
- **ejb** is not a protocol. You need to setup your client very differently to use that jndi prefix (described in your links). It tries to save you a server call (i.e. the jndi lookup) and at the same time support a WildFly cluster

For a detailed explanation of all this see
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Comment: In all cases those are first parts of URI. I should use word 'scheme' instead of 'protocol', right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Though for http-remoting and remoting there actually is a difference in terms of network protocol.